# Which format does moment.js support for zone abbreviation

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I am not able to find a format to convert date to string with abbreviation, for example :

`moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A z')` converts to `09/17/2019 05:00 PM`

Is there a way to convert it to `09/17/2019 05:00 AM PST`? (where PSt is my browser's TZ)

Comment: Have you checked out [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `moment-timezone` library (with timezone data) and guess the user's timezone using `moment.tz.guess()`.

```js
console.log(appendTimezone('09/17/2019 05:00 PM', {
  timeZone   : 'America/Los_Angeles',
  dateFormat : 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
}));

function appendTimezone(timestamp, options) {
  options = options || {};
  let zone = options.timeZone || moment.tz.guess();
  let frmt = options.dateFormat || 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ';
  return moment(timestamp, frmt).format(frmt) + ' ' + moment().tz(zone).format('z');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.26/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

### Another example

```js
const DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A z';

let now = moment(),
    localTimeZone = moment.tz.guess();

let localTimeStamp = now.tz(localTimeZone);
console.log(localTimeStamp.format(DATE_FORMAT));

let pacificTimeStamp = now.tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(pacificTimeStamp.format(DATE_FORMAT));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.26/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will change the time as per the timezone, isn't there any way to keep the date time intact

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean by "keep the date time intact"?

Comment: @RaT Ok, I see what you mean... you just want to concatenate the time zone? I will update with an example of this.

Comment: @RaT I added parsing/formatting of the input timestamp, but this is just extraneous...

Comment: thanks for the update, 
But again this wouldn't give correct abbreviation on edge cases of DST change, suppose I am on UTC and I try to get moment().tz(zone).format('z') with zone as America/Los_Angeles for date 03/10/2019 4:00 then it should have given PDT but due to timezone conversion it will change the date time to 03/09/2019 20:00 and give abbreviation as PST.

Comment: @RaT If you just described what it needs to do, then you know how to implement it?